# Как сохранить стэк фрагментов приложения на Android при смене ориентации?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Как сохранить стэк фрагментов? У меня приложение построено на архитектуре **SingleActivity**, то есть, у меня одно **MainActivity** и много фрагментов. Я хочу что бы приложение при смене ориентации полностью восстанавливало свое состояние вплоть до стэка фрагментов.Что бы можно было при нажатии кнопки назад, перейти в предыдущий фрагмент. Например в приложении ВКонтакте так и сделано. При смене ориентации приложение запускается с того экрана при котором было произведено изменение ориентации. Но при этом, если нажать на кнопку назад вы попадете в предыдущий экран. 
Я использую MVVM, я понимаю, что можно работать с LiveData и определять какой экран надо запустить при смене ориентации, это не проблема. Но как восстановить стэк фрагментов? Что бы можно было вернуться в предыдущий фрагмент, даже после смены ориентации. 
Если какие нибудь кейсы или статьи где описано как правильно восстановить приложение после смены ориентации , неважно на Kotlin или Java.

Comment: используйте [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation), там уже из коробки поддерживается данный функционал

Comment: Спасибо, но мне маленько другое надо было.

Comment: Не могли бы вы подробнее указать где можно про это прочитать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После прочтения этой [статьи](https://blog.propaneapps.com/android/fragments-restoration-magic/), я понял, что надо сохранять не стэк фрагментов а менеджер фрагментов. Андроид автоматически сохраняет менеджер фрагментов при смене ориентации,
если установить флаг `retainInstance = true` в методе `onStop()`.

```
 override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        retainInstance = true
    }
```

. Дальше вам надо в главном Activity проверить

```
if (savedInstanceState==null){
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, Fragment1()).commit()
        }
```

И все, при смене ориентации вы попадете на тот же фрагмент на котором произошло изменение. И самое главное вы полностью восстановите стэк фрагментов.

Есть требование, у всех ваших фрагментов должен быть **пустой** конструктор.

Что бы все проверить, накидал быстренько приложение из трех фрагментов, все отлично работает, стэк восстанавливается.

Comment: а что это за функция Fragment1() ? и на retainInstance  AndroidStudio ругается

Answer (score 1):

Сохранить сам стек у вас скорее всего не получится  т.к. все что живёт внутри активити умирает. Но вы можете заново открыть все фрагменты в том же порядке при воссоздании активити.

Можно создать свой стек в котором будут лежать теги фрагментов (enum или строковые константы). Каждый раз при добавлении фрагмента вы в этот стек кладете тэг. Если вы извлекаете фрагмент, соответственно извлекается и тэг. При повороте экрана вы через вашу ViewModel передаёте этот стек и пот нему заново все восстанавливаете.

Конечно для такой задачи лучше вообще подумать о том, чтоб создать какой-то навигационный компонент, в котором вся эта логика будет обрабатываться. Чтоб активити ничего не знала о тегах и прочей кухне.

Возможно стоит посмотреть в сторону Google Navigation Component или Cicerone от Яндекса. Эти фреймворки рассчитаны на навигацию и вполне возможно, что ребята там уже решили живу проблему.

Вот [эта статья](https://blog.propaneapps.com/android/fragments-restoration-magic/) должна помочь в вашей проблеме.

Comment: Я тоже про это думал, в принципе ход решения я думаю у вас правильный. Но я так прикинул, громоздко это получится. Хотя как вариант конечно можно и так. Я думал, может кто встречался с такой проблемой и соответственно как ее решили.Не могу еще представить как использовать Googy Navigation Component , для решения это проблемы).

Comment: Ну это проблема не тривиальная, чтоб решалась в 10 строчек=) В лучшем случае вы найдете готовое решение под капотом которого будет примерно +- то же самое. Как ни крути вам придется хранить этот стек самостоятельно, и восстанавливать так же, вопрос только в том в каком виде и где вы будете это хранить и как вы будете с этим стеком работать.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное за статью, там хорошо описан механизм сохранения фрагментов. Почему я не натолкнулся на эту статью раньше)). Теперья я понял, что проблема решается очень легко. Так как Android может сам сохранять менеджер фрагментов при смене ориентации. Для того,  что бы сохранение произошло,  надо во фрагменте в методе onStop установить флаг  retainInstance = true, а в методе onCreate надо проверить savedInstanceState==null.  И все, после смены ориентации вы попадает на тот же фрагмент и самое главное вы полностью вернете стэк фрагментов.